# Getting unexpected end of file on a base_aliases function

Tags: bash, function

Tearing my hair out trying to work out why this function in my ~/.bash_aliases is causing an error.

```
function kill-xbmc () { xbmcpid=`ps aux | grep "[x]bmc" | awk "{printf "%s ",$2}"`; kill -9 ${xbmcpid} }
```

It keeps producing the same end of file error. I can't seem to see that I'm missing a pair of {} or "" marks or anything overly obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function kill-xbmc () { xbmcpid=`ps aux | grep "[x]bmc" | awk '{printf "%s ",$2}'`; kill -9 ${xbmcpid}; }
```

The last statement in the function was not ended with `;` so the closing `}` was taken as part of the last statement. The remaining lines of the script are assumed to be part of the function, hence the "unexpected end of file" error when no matching closing braces were found.

I also changed the quotes for your `awk` arguments. You were using the same quote characters for nested quotes and the string was therefore being terminated prematurely.

```
awk "{printf "%s ",$2}"
    ---------  | ------
        |      |     |
       s1      |    s2   
               |
         %s outside string
```

Note that I used the single quotes for the outer ones to make sure that `$2` is not expanded by the shell.

Comment: Works a treat and the detailed explanation make so much sense. This is why I love how useful stackoverflow is!